# Excluding records based on multiple criteria with specific values in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

**Information:**

I have one table with three columns: Book, Store_1, and Store_2.  I'm using MS Access, but am also familiar with MySQL as well.

```
_______________________________________________
      Book        |   Store_1   |   Store_2   |
Lord of the Rings |   Paper     |             |
Ender's Game      |   Digital   |   Digital   |
Mistborn          |   Digital   |             |
Spines            |             |   Paper     |
Grapes of Wrath   |             |   Digital   |
Artemis Fowl      |             |             |
Redwall           |   Paper     |   Paper     |
Perloo the Bold   |   Digital   |   Paper     |
_______________________________________________
```

**Issue**

I need to write a single query that will exclude a row if it meets any of the following criteria:

- Exclude row where cell for Store 2 is null.  Even if Store 1 is not null, exclude this row anyways based on Store 2 being null.
- Exclude row where cell for Store 1 and Store 2 are both "Digital".  For any record that has "Digital" for Store 1 AND store 2, exclude it.
- Exclude row where cell for Store 1 and Store 2 are both "Null".  For rows where both Store 1 and Store 2 are null for the same record, exclude it.

The table should look like this after running the query:

```
_______________________________________________
      Book        |   Store_1   |   Store_2   |
Spines            |             |   Paper     |
Grapes of Wrath   |             |   Digital   |
Redwall           |   Paper     |   Paper     |
Perloo the Bold   |   Digital   |   Paper     |
_______________________________________________
```

**What I've Tried**

I'm going to be honest and say I don't know how to combine all three criteria into one statement.  The closest I've got... is *getting the opposite of what I want*, which is with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Books
WHERE (Store_2 IS NULL) OR (Store_1 AND Store_2 = "Digital") OR (Store_1 AND Store_2 IS NULL)
;
```

It gives me the books I **do not** want, which is a start, but I cannot figure out how to reverse it.  I get a syntax error when adding NOT IN after WHERE.  Thanks for any help, advice, or guidance down the right road you can provide.

Comment: I see no store_3 here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `NULL` condition is superfluous as it can only be true if the first one is true. So you can simplify your expression to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Books
WHERE Store_2 IS NOT NULL AND NOT (Store_2 <=> 'Digital' AND Store_1 <=> 'Digital')
```

Output:

```
Book                Store_1     Store_2
Spines                          Paper
Grapes of Wrath                 Digital
Redwall             Paper       Paper
Perloo the Bold     Digital     Paper
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9e59a1225e0a27124744f20dc8631e29)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  Trying out your solution returned the lines for "Lord of the Rings" and "Ender's Game".  I realized I should have been more clear on my exclusion criteria.

- Exclude row where cell for Store 1 and Store 2 are both "Digital".  I meant exclude records where BOTH cells are "Digital" at the same time.
- Exclude row where cell for Store 1 and Store 2 are both "Null".  Again, exclude records where Store 1 and Store 2's cells are "Null" for a single record.

Comment: @user12475155 my bad - I forgot to allow for NULL-safe comparisons. I've updated the query and added a working demo. Sorry...

Comment: Nick, you wouldn't happen to know the null-safe equal to operator in Access do you?  I know I say I know MySQL as well, but unfortunately I've never used it and can't find anything online on how to translate it to Access.  Other than that, your query reads correct and I understand where I went wrong.

Comment: @user12475155 I don't think access has one. You would need to use `WHERE Store_2 IS NOT NULL AND NOT (Store_2 = 'Digital' AND Store_2 IS NOT NULL AND Store_1 = 'Digital' AND Store_1 IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

THis eill do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Books
WHERE (Store_2 IS NOT NULL) AND (Store_1 <> 'Digital' OR Store_2 <> 'Digital') AND (Store_1 ÌS NOT NULL OR Store_2 IS NOT NULL)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

@zip was close, but has a hidden backtick in second`Store_1 IS NOT NULL`and the null-safe compare for any stores not equal to 'digital' or NULL, is to check`Store_1`for Null, as Store_2 can't be Null, because of first criteria.

Now if one of those criteria is met, data is displayed.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Books
WHERE Store_2 IS NOT NULL
    AND (
        Store_1 <> 'Digital'
        OR Store_2 <> 'Digital'
        OR Store_1 IS NOT NULL
        );
```

[Common Errors with Null](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-12.html) may enlight OP on getting null-safe in`Ms Access`.

One last remark.

Fieldnames with a number (especialy in sequence), smell like bad normalization. Usually you would have a column for the store number, what makes you free to have an unlimited number of stores.

For later display the data with store-number in columns, you can [create a crosstab-query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465B89C-2FF2-4CC8-BA60-2CD8484667E8)